# Custom VM specs in Azure?

Tags: azure

I'm spinning up VMs in Microsoft Azure Cloud, and want to set my own VM size/specs
without using any of the existing DS / A / blah sizes.

e.g. 4 CPUs, 8GB RAM, 20GB SSD C: Drive - that is all I need, no more no less.

Does Azure allow this level of customization, or am I stuck with their existing templates ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Simple answer though: No. You may only choose VM sizes that are advertised. Same as it's always ever been. Not sure what you mean by "stuck with existing templates" though - there are dozens of configurations available. Also, the SSD drive you're referring to? That's temporary storage. You still get to choose the attached-storage durable SSD you want, from 32GB to 1TB per disk.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, none of the dozens of configurations suit my need - there is no template for the specs I mentioned in my question. the available specs are also displayed in random order, and we can't filter by cpu/ram/disk etc., so it makes a newcomer's task annoying. And this question, while not strictly about programming, might have a programmatic answer, say powershell or other commands.

Comment: The F4S has 4 core, 8GB, with 32GB SSD c: drive (the smallest SSD disk available - you cannot create one smaller, as you'll still pay for the full 32gb). And your question has nothing to do with PowerShell. It's just about sizing.

Comment: @d-_-b Does it work now? Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Azure allow this level of customization?

For now, Azure does **not** support custom VM size.

**Update:**

As a workaround, we can **create** a VM in your local Hyper-V, and set VM's vhd size to 50GB.

After VM create completed, we can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image) to **prepare a VHD**.
like enable RDP, open windows firewall, install Azure VM agent and so on.

Then we can use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#blob-upload) to **upload VHD** to Azure storage account blob, script like this:

```
AzCopy /Source:D:\test /Dest:https://jasondisk321.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/ /DestKey:K7aUYrCxxx7mJ/np0/SMZ2niXElHUxW7u8GUmbnz0C8nQvNmuEDpScvX4X9i+l8gtXSVy40215SOLpP8cCBAvQ== /Pattern:jason200.vhd /BlobType:page
```

We can download Azcopy from this [page](http://aka.ms/downloadazcopy). Azcopy only work for windows.

After that, we can use [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd) to create Azure VM with this VHD. Like this:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't allow for any different vm sizes to be created. The vm specs are independent of a vhd and don't impact any choices made when creating a vm, either through the portal or ARM template.